# Search users that follow user with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got one **page** in table **pages** with:

> id = 1, name, lastname

I got the table **followers** with these fields:

> page_id, follower_id

And I got the table **users**, with these fields:

> id, name, lastname, photo, friendly_url

I got 'search', what the user write, and the *$id* of the **page**:

```
public function u_followers_search($id) {
  $_POST['search']
}
```

I want to search all the users that follow the page with the $_POST['search'] and show these users...

Comment: "search post" what do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: But the search is to filter the page name or username?

Comment: I edited my question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Followers::select('users.*')
->leftJoin('users', 'followers.follower_id', '==', 'user.id')
->where('page.id', $id )
->get();
```

Assuming your follower id is user.id (foreign key relation between followers table and users table).

Answer (score 0):

With laravel elequent.

```
//Page.php
public function users()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
     'App\User',
     'App\Follower', // followers model
     'page_id',      // Foreign key in Follower
     'id',  // Foreign key in Users
     'id',           // Local key Page
     'follower_id'            // Local key Users
  );
 }

//Controller
public function u_followers_search(Request $request) {
  $page = Page::find($request->id);
  return $page->load([
     'users' => function($query) use ($request){
       $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
       ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
     }
   ]);
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.follower_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `followers`.`user_id` from `users`

Comment: Ooops, my bad, please check answer again

Comment: I try, but don't works, return all the users of table, no only the followers.

Comment: if you try `dd($request);` at the start of the function, what does it return?

Comment: Return the id and the post.